# Counting all homomorphism from $S_4$ to $\mathbb{Z_6}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I have to count number of homomorphism from $S_4$ to $\mathbb{Z_6}$.

One approach that I know is by finding the possible kernel of homomorphism from $S_4$ to $\mathbb{Z_6}$.

I am using another approach by finding the generators of $S_4$. We know that 
$S_4$ can  be generated by a $2$-cycle, say $\sigma$ and a $3$-cycle, say $\tau$: Thus any homomorphism $f\colon S_4\to \mathbb{Z_6}$ can be determined by finding  $f(\tau)$ and $f(\sigma)$ completely. It is clear that $f(\sigma)^2=1$ since $\sigma^2=1$ and $f(\tau)^3=1$ since $\tau^3=1$. Now we have to search for possible number of elements in $Z_6$ whose order divide $2$ and $3$ respectively.

**My confusion:**
We know that $S_4$ can also be generated by a $2$-cycle and a $4$-cycle. Perhaps, above written procedure may give wrong results in such case since order of four cycle is $4$. I am not able to understand where I am going wrong.

I would be very much grateful if anybody could clear my doubt.  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Any such homomorphism factors through the abelianization of $S_4$. Do you know what that is?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I haven't studied abelianization of group. Could you explain little?

Comment: The short answer is that if $f : G \to A$ is a homomorphism of groups and $A$ is abelian, then every commutator $ghg^{-1} h^{-1} \in G$ has the property that $f(ghg^{-1} h^{-1}) = f(g) f(h) f(g)^{-1} f(h)^{-1} = f(g) f(g)^{-1} f(h) f(h)^{-1} = 1$ because $A$ is abelian, hence every commutator lies in $\text{ker}(f)$. Commutators generate a subgroup of $G$ called its commutator subgroup $[G, G]$, and so $[G, G]$ always lies in the kernel of any group homomorphism from $G$ to an abelian group. The group $G/[G, G]$ itself is in particular abelian and is called the abelianization.

Comment: So, try to figure out what elements of $S_4$ are commutators and you'll figure out what elements must be in the kernel.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you very much. I will study more about abelianization. In this case I think abelization of $S_4$ would be of order $2$ and hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}$. So my problem reduces to finding the possible homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z_2}$ to $\mathbb{Z_6}$. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very similar to another recent question that asks to find [all homomorphisms from $S_4$ to $\Bbb Z_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764816/find-all-homomorphism-from-s-4-to-mathbbz-2/808472#808472). Certainly one of the simpler ways to answer your question is to determine the possible images of a transposition $\tau$. Once you know $\phi(\tau)$ for some transposition $\tau$, you have completely described the homomorphism $\phi$ since the transpositions generate $S_n$ and are all conjugate (so that their image is the same in the abelian target group). The only constraint on $\phi(\tau)$ is that be of order $2$. Hence,

> If $G$ is an abelian group, there is one non-trivial morphism $S_n\to G$ for every element $g\in G$ or order $2$ (and the trivial morphism of course).

There is only one element of order $2$ in $\Bbb Z_6$, the element $3$, so that there is precisely one non trivial morphism $S_4\to\Bbb Z_6$ (plus the trivial morphism of course).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please correct me If I am wrong. Since $S_4$ can be generated by transpositions so by finding $\phi(\tau)$ we can count all possible homomorphism and order of $\phi(\tau)$ must be divisor of $2$. So, there are only two possible homomorphism in this case.

Comment: @srijan yes, but you need to say that there is only _one_ element of order 2 in $\Bbb Z_6$. If you were to look for homomorphisms with target $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ for instance, you'd get 3 non trivial homorphisms, because there are three elements of order 2 in this (abelian) group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You cleared my doubt completely. Thank you very much.